# .msi file doesn't run in my pc windows 8 professional

Tags: windows, operating-system

**.MSI file** doesn't run in my Laptop windows 8 professional any help please.
while it runs in friend's Laptop.
How can i run it
When i run my file it ask which application you want to run this file?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe .msi file extension was somehow unregistered from its application (msiexec.exe), which should be already installed. Try entering this in command prompt:

```
msiexec /i path_to_your_install_file.msi
```

If this starts the installation, then you should later eventually reregister .msi files. How to do that would be another story.

Comment: its not working and when try to open my file with **msiexec.exe** it says can't associate this program with this file.